# Speed difference in explicit redirection

Tags: bash

What is the difference between

```
sed -ne '10{p;q;}' file.txt
```

&

```
sed -ne '10{p;q;}' <file.txt
```

?

I know what `sed` is doing here and all that I am concerned is the way input is passed. Just that I took a `sed` example.

I believe (**this can be a serious misunderstanding too**) in **both** the cases something similar to below :

```
 exec 4<&0; exec 0<file.txt;sed -ne '10{p;q;}'-;exec 0<&4
```

is happening (by 4, i just mean a temporary file descriptor).

So both should be equally fast. **Am I wrong**?

Comment: Not quite correct; in the first case sed can use mmap-ed input, which may be faster, and there are probably other less or more significant differences.

Answer (score 2):

Both will end up with a file descriptor to the file being handled by sed, the difference being who effectively open()s the file, but the rest is the same. Contrast with useless use of cat and a pipe. Performance impact could be more relevant with grep (esp. GNU grep) who does really smart things upon an open fd vs a simpler stdin stream.

Comment: Thanks for that info on `GNU grep`.